# A compact operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I'd like to show that a compact linear operator $T: X \to Y$ between normed spaces is bounded. Can you tell me if this is right?

If $T$ is compact, then the closure of the image of $B(0,1)$ and hence of $B(0,n)$ is compact. Then $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Tx\| \leq \sup_{x \in B(0,2)} \|Tx\| \leq K$ for some $K \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ since $TB(0,2) \subset \overline{TB(0,2)}$ and $\overline{TB(0,2)}$ is compact hence bounded.

Comment: That's right${}$

Comment: You should state what $K$ is.

Comment: @DavidMitra Done!

Comment: Matt, this is precisely what I was getting at in the comments for this question previously. Good work.

Comment: @J.Loreaux Thank you for your comments. I was too embarrassed about the mistake I made there and had to delete my previous question.