# weakly continuous linear map

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, compact-operators

The following is a Theorem of Murphy's C*-algebra and operator theory:[image]

To prove the theorem, the author claims compact linear map $u$ is weakly continuous. I know that every bounded linear map is weakly continuous, but I'm not sure each linear map is weakly continuous, too. Maybe compactness of $u$ implies  weakly continuity of $u$ or he suppose that $u$ is bounded.

Please give me a hint to prove  every linear map ( compact linear map ) is weakly continuous, or a counterexample for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183638/a-compact-operator-is-bounded).

Comment: @DavidMitra:  Thanks